# Is it possible to create search layouts in a custom Object?

Tags: custom-object, search-layout

I'm creating custom objects in a new ORG in Salesforce based on a custom object in an old ORG.

I notice the old custom object has 6 search layouts while the newly created object only has 4 search layouts. The fields are basically the same.
The Salesforce Editions are also the same (Enterprise Edition).

Is it possible to add Search Layouts to my custom Object?

Comment: Have you created a tab for the new custom object as that creates a search layout for the tab and the list view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that there are only 4 search layouts for a searchable custom object is that you have not created a Tab for it, which means a Tab and List View search layout have not been created yet.

I have created a new custom object and made it searchable, but not created a tab, it has 4 search layouts.

[image: Object no tab]

Same object after adding a tab - 6 layouts now exist.
[image]

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation which says we need a tab for search layout to work. Do you know if there is any documentation for this? much appreciated. cheers!

Comment: I haven't been able to find documentation but at the time I wrote the answer experimenting in Dev orgs and Sandboxes confirmed that what I said was correct.